# How can I use validates between two tables ? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a table `items` and a  table `proms`. `items` has a column `prom` and `prom` has a column `promname`, I want in my `item` model to validate if `Prom.exists?(:promanme => :prom) then create else I don't have that prom stored yet

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validates :prom_exist?
def prom_exist?
      if Prom.exists?(:promane => :prom)
      else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validate :prom_exists

  def prom_exists
    errors.add(:prom, 'does not exist') if prom && !Prom.exists?(promnane: prom)
  end
end
```

Although I would recommend making a foreign key constraint and using a prom's `id` instead of it's name and `Item` would just have `prom_id` and `item.prom` would fetch the `Prom` record. Then it would simply like:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prom
end
```